# Can an ABS drain be fitted to a PVC waste pipe riser?

Tags: drain, drain-waste-vent, pvc, abs

The only shower drain available at my local hardware store is The Wondercap, which looks fine.

However, the (white) plastic is formed with "`ABS`", and the drain pipe itself is white plastic, which I assume to be PVC.

(Isn't ABS supposed to be colored black?)

**Is there a safe way to bond these two pieces together?** Or should I go find a real plumbing shop and buy a different drain, made out of PVC?

---

Note the missing drain at the top of the riser:
[image: photo of drain pipe from below the trap]

And, the rough hole from above:
[image]

Comment: ABS plumbing pipe is made black by convention, but ABS in a raw form is a translucent off white and can be made it almost any color.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Lego bricks are made of ABS plastic :)

Comment: They make glue that is good for both ABS and PVC. Check the plumbing department at your nearest big box store.

Comment: @isherwood: Photos of pipe uploaded. The Wondercap drain info is at http://wondercap.com/products/wondercap/

Comment: Followup on this question: I installed a different drain, made of PVC.